# I can't do a complete upgrade in 14.04 due to LXC 2.0.3 related packages

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, lxc

The following packages are held back when I try to upgrade my system [using GUI or command line "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade"]:

liblxc1 lxc lxc-common lxc-templates lxc1 python3-lxc

Should I worry about it? Or is it just a matter of waiting some time?

I understood this behavior reflects last Ubuntu version release  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). But, I am just an user with some notions of computing. I prefer checking out before doing any mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If the packages are held back but other ones are updated, It's **normal**. `apt-get update` **never** change any package only update the installed packages. I asssume that you have installed lxc packages from backports or ppa. So you have two options:

1. Wait that the packages are updated in backports/ppa.
2. **apt-get dist-upgrade**. this command replace any package that you have installed for equivalents, uninstalling older ones. With care, because only in extreme cases `atp-get dist-upgrade` only uninstall older ones and don't install equivalent packages.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! Actually, I haven't installed lxc packages from backports or ppa. I was only referring to the information I found about it.

Comment: Considering I haven't installed them, is it just a matter of waiting for the next packages upgrades, until dependencies are OK and those packages (or future versions of them) may be installed?

Comment: If you are not installed this packages. You can try to uninstall, but with care, because the packages was not installed by you, but maybe can be some dependence from another package that you install.